# Iterating a value from inside an 'onClick'

Tags: android, arrays, methods

I'm using the logic below to iterate through an array names[] and show a different result on button click.

```
i = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_INDEX, 0);
    j = i;

while (i==j)
    {
        j=j+1;
    final TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vNames);
    String vName = names[i];
    nameView.setText(vName);

    Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i=i+1;
            return;
        };
    });
    }
```

My problem is getting out of the onClick method with the new values. The code is getting stuck inside the onClick. (I've checked what's happening using System.out.println() in various places in the code.)
I've used the above

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            i=i+1;
            return;
        };
```

method, which runs without error but doesn't give me the result. I've also tried something like

```
public int onClick(View v) {
            i=i+1;
            return i; //or return int i;
        };
```

but this gives me the error "The return type is incompatible with View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)".

Any ideas on how to deal with this or alternative methods would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to understand that setOnClickListener is not blocking until you actually click on it. It returns immediatly, and your loop is looping forever, blocking the UI thread and everything else.

Comment: You need to have some knowledge about java `Anonymous Classes` before learning android, then only you will understand your problem.

Comment: You should also learn to use the debugger.  System.out is not an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you want is to increase the value of "i" every time you press the button, then change the text on nameview? Try this:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
        i++;
        nameView.setText(names[i]);
    };
});
```

However you will eventually run out of names. If you want to repeat the values from the start, try this:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
        i++;
        nameView.setText(names[i%names.length]);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most workable solution for now (if not as elegant as I had wanted it to be).

Answer (score 0):

onClick() is called by the system so even if it did return a value, you have no way of getting it - its returned back to where it's called, which is a component of the system.

What you need to do is define a value outside of the scope of the onClick() method, i.e. a member of your class, and set it from within your method. Then that value will persist across method calls.

I'd also like to point out that you are defining the onClick() method for your nextButton Button over and over and over within the while loop. Looking at the code, i don't see why you would want to do that... but at the same time, your loop condition (i==j) is only true for the first iteration of the loop. J is set to i outside of the loop, so the loop runs the first time, j is incremented by 1 (j=j+1) and the next iteration checks the condition, i is still its original value and so j no longer matches to i, so this loop will only run once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int i;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    this.i = 3;

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            incrementI();
            tv.setText(Integer.valueOf(i).toString());
        }
    });
    }

    public void incrementI()
    {
        this.i = this.i + 1;
    }
}
```

You can call a method which increments a value.

```
public int onClick(View v) {
            i=i+1;
            return i; //or return int i;
        };
```

This can't work because there is no method called onClick() which returns an integer.
When you use a variable in OnClickListener it must be final.